# Div with image and floating text

Tags: css

How would you solve to put an image inside div with H1 header and a text across the image at the bottom with transparent grey background?

```
DIV:
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|                                     | 
|  |------------------------------|   |
|  |H1 text                       |   |
|  |                              |   |
|  |------------------------------|   |
|  |image                         |   |
|  |                              |   |
|  |                              |   |                       
|  |------------------------------|   |
|  |text floating over image      |   |
|  |with grey transprarent bg     |   | 
|  -------------------------------    |
 -------------------------------------
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? is the image part of the content or is it just for styling purposes?

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you; post your code and we can comment.